# React - passing component prop in click handlers passed as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React. I have a react component `Child` like this -

```
//this.props has obj = {'id': 123, 'name': 'abc'}
class Child extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div onClick={this.props.remove}></div>
        );
    }
}
```

This component is being used from some `Parent` component which has a list of such `Child` component, each having their own `this.props.obj`. `this.props.remove` is another handler passed to `Child` from `Parent`.

Now, on click of `div` redered from `Child` component, I want to pass `this.props.obj.id` in remove function. How can I do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to React!

[You can learn about event handlers here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

I would write it up like this;

```
class Child extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    handleClick({id}) {
       this.props.remove(id)
    }

    render(){
        const obj = this.props
        return(
            <div onClick={() => this.handleClick(obj)}></div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is {id} inside the argument of handleClick. Is it destructuring? Just confirming

Comment: Yes, it is destructuring. Helps your functions & overall codebase stay clean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrow functions to achieve this.

```js
class Child extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div onClick={() => this.props.remove(this.props.obj.id)}></div>
        );
    }
}
```